# Getting android device galaxy S2 work like an emulator

Tags: android, web-services, android-emulator, galaxy

I want to test my app on a android device, I have a local webservice (ASP.net) that is hosted in my laptop in local, when I plug my device, the app works in it but it cannot receive data from my local webservice, how can I get the data sent to the device just like in the emulator 
PS: the app works properly in the emulator.
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The emulator uses your laptop's network interfaces, hence it can access webservice directly. Your device needs to connect to your laptop via its own connectivity options (celluar network, WiFi, possibly bluetooth).

I have a few ideas how to get there:

- If you have got a WiFi router and both your laptop and phone connect to it - that's pretty straightforward: just expose webservice to address that can be seen within network and use it on your phone.
- If you've got an external IP - just use that address when phone is connected to network.
- Set up a WiFi access point on your laptop and connect your device with it

  Check these URLs how to set up a hosted network (hotspot) on Windows 7:

  [Hosted network documentation in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd815243%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

  [Hosted network tutorial](http://www.wi-fiplanet.com/tutorials/article.php/3849841/How-to-Create-Wireless-Hosted-Networks-in-Windows-7.htm)
- You might try Bluetooth and PAN.

Comment: thank you for you help, how can I expose my webservice to an adress that can be seen within network? I'm real beginner and I don't know how to do it

Comment: if you have 2 computers, ping each other on their network addresses and try opening webservice on the other using the address.

Comment: I can ping the computer but I can't access the web service from the browser (ipadress/myapp/WebService1.asmx, they tell me can't access to the ip adress, is there something I'm missing? I'm using IIS in my app

Comment: You need to look at your IIS config what addresses it is running on. Possibly only 127.0.0.1 by default.

Comment: No problem. That's why we are both here :)